# Why isn't my thread storing its result in an array before the program completes?

Tags: c, pthreads

I've been looking around for a good while, but no solution - like thread_join or pthread_exit - seems to work for me. I'm trying to have a thread (several if I can get one to work) evaluate something, and store a 1 on a position in a zeroed array if successful, but my program finishes (or at least prints the array) before the thread can edit the array. Here is some equivalent code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define numThreads 1
#define resultSize 6

/* function definitions */
void setZero(int[]);
void printResultArray(int[]);
void *setResult(void *);

int resultArray[resultSize];

/* main Program */
int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    pthread_t tid[numThreads];
    setZero(resultArray);   
    printf("Creating worker thread..\n");
    for(i = 0;i < numThreads; i++)
        tid[i] = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, setResult, NULL);
    for(i = 0;i < numThreads; i++)
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

  //  sleep(1);
    printf("Array values: ");
    printResultArray(resultArray);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *setResult(void *param){
    resultArray[0] = 1;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void printResultArray(int results[]) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<resultSize; i++) 
        printf("%d ", results[i]);
     printf("\n");
}

void setZero(int results[]) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<resultSize; i++) 
        results[i] = 0;
}
```

If the comment on sleep(1) is removed I get my desired 100000, otherwise I get all zeroes, but obviously I don't want it to sleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tid[i] = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, setResult, NULL);` trashes `tid[i]` with the value returned from the `pthread_create()` call.

[`pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) returns a indication of success (0) or failure (an error number) — it doesn't return a `pthread_t` object.

Most likely, your call to `pthread_join()` is returning immediately with an error.